# How do I introduce a float value in this Java code?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class CheckbookBalancingCalculator {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        String statementbalance, depositstotal, checkstotal, feestotal;
        int statement, deposits, checks, fees, index;
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ));

        System.out.println( "\tBalancing Your Checkbook:" );
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the balance from your last statement?" );
        statementbalance = dataIn.readLine();
        statement = Integer.parseInt( statementbalance );
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the total amount of all deposits?" );
        depositstotal = dataIn.readLine();
        deposits = Integer.parseInt( depositstotal );
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the total amount of all checks?" );
        checkstotal = dataIn.readLine();
        checks = Integer.parseInt( checkstotal );
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the total amount of all transaction fees?" );
        feestotal = dataIn.readLine();
        fees = Integer.parseInt( feestotal );

        index = statement + deposits - checks - fees;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "\tYour new balance is " + Math.round( index ) + "." );
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question here really?

Comment: @Noel - look at the answers he's gotten. I'd suggest the problem is that he's not getting enough answers to accept a best answer... @nolimitsplayer - phrasing questions more clearly will encourage a greater quantity and quality of responses.

Answer (score 2):

Floats/Doubles are a bad idea.  US Currency is a fixed decimal calculation.

```
String statementBalanceInput, depositsTotalInput, checksTotalInput, feesTotalInput;
int statement, deposits, checks, fees, index;

BigDecimal statementBalance = new BigDecimal( statementBalanceInput);
BigDecimal depositsTotal = new BigDecimal( depositsTotalInput);
BigDecimal checksTotal = new BigDecimal( checksTotalInput);
BigDecimal feesTotal = new BigDecimal( feesTotalInput);
```

This is off the top of my head.  Then do the math with BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.*;

public class CheckbookBalancingCalculator {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        String statementbalance, depositstotal, checkstotal, feestotal;
        float statement, deposits, checks, fees, index;
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ));

        System.out.println( "\tBalancing Your Checkbook:" );
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the balance from your last statement?" );
        statementbalance = dataIn.readLine();
        statement = Float.parseFloat( statementbalance );
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the total amount of all deposits?" );
        depositstotal = dataIn.readLine();
        deposits = Float.parseFloat( depositstotal );
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the total amount of all checks?" );
        checkstotal = dataIn.readLine();
        checks = Float.parseFloat( checkstotal );
        System.out.print( "\t\tWhat is the total amount of all transaction fees?" );
        feestotal = dataIn.readLine();
        fees = Float.parseFloat( feestotal );

        index = statement + deposits - checks - fees;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "\tYour new balance is " + Math.round( index ) + "." );
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Erick -1 for being non-humorus with an fun answer to a realy bad question. Beseides I have exactly done what you find in the question title.

Comment: Last time I checked, this wasn't a humorous site.  I upvote responses which are helpful, and downvote ones that are unhelpful.

Comment: @Erick *sigh* you take it much too serious, that what I wanted to show you. DV where it makes sense, not here since it was a really crappy question which I have answerd correcly but not helpful.

Comment: Certainly not correctly.  I can guarantee you that this answer does not address the intent of the question.

Comment: @Erick This is up to the interpretation of this extream vague question. I have edited my answer to make you a bit happy. You dont seem to get my sence of humor.

Comment: @InsertNickHere I get your sense of humour! :)

Comment: @Erick, I would be willing to bet that you couldn't address the intent of the question. Not incapable but unable. The difference is due to its inscrutability. Nobody could in its current form, hence its closure.  @InsertNickHere - Nice try at making lemonade when handed lemons.

Comment: @Kelly: Actually, the intent of the question seems clear that he wants to modify the code to support floats instead of ints.  Seems a bit basic, but I think it's mostly clear that's what he's asking.  To that extent, this answer actually answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are probably looking for is Float.parseFloat() or Double.parseDouble(), depending on required precision.

If you happen to accept currency / numeric values in different formats, depending on locale, try NumberFormat methods instead (passing valid Locale object).

Comment: Single? Surely you mean Float.

Comment: -1 there is no class `Single`

Comment: Thanks, of course I meant Float. Too much of C# I guess.